# How can I remove a Google Business listing that has a similar brand name to mine?

Tags: google-search, google-my-business, google-business

When I search for my brand name "Branded", I can see a Google business listing on the side including the map and this takes up page space and it's an entirely different company called "Brannded".

Note: The names are different. The other company is not a competitor. It is a restaurant, whereas my business is e-commerce and I cannot apply for Google Business since we don't have bricks and mortar. However, as these names are branded names not part of the dictionary it is taking traction, customers and I don't want it listed.

What can I do?

Comment: As an official company you surely declared a head office with a postal adress you could register to Google my business, nope?

Comment: Cant simply be a mailing address. Needs a physical store/business location at which they do face to face business with clients, or needs a service area where they physically visit clients at the client's location to provide services to the client. Cannot simply be an online only ecommerce business, even if they do have a mailing address.

Answer (score 4):

"I don't want it listed" isn't a valid reason for it's removal.

Considering it's showing for a result for a branded search, Google is likely going to include it in the results, as a person may have made a typing a error when typing in their search query.

As you have said, it is not a competitor, so you aren't likely to lose any business to them with having them display in search results. If someone is looking for your site and types in your business/site name, then they are already familiar with/know of your business/brand in some way.

Why not work on SEO to increase the organic traffic from people that do not know your brand/business/website, that would be interested in and searching for your ecommerce products.

Businesses that have a GMB listing, qualify for a local panel to show.
Unfortunately, it's not possible to claim a knowledge panel for a brand or person, Google will decide if to display one, based on a brand's or person's authority.

You may want to look into how to optimize to increase your chances of google showing a knowledge panel for your online business or brand

**eta**

> "But it is a spelling mistake. The names are different."

Google Search will usually include different results for typos and spelling variations of a search query, especially common or oftenly occurring ones.  One of the reasons why businesses will often pay to show up in paid search results for competitors business names, brand terms and misspelled variations of them.

> "Can I not report the map listing as copyright and ask for it to be
>   removed on that basis."

If that is their legal business name, how is it copyright infringement?

I'm not an attorney, so obviously cannot offer legal advice.
Having said that, usually a business name would not be covered by copyright.
It would come under trademarks (if there were a registered trademark) and then it breaks down into what class of goods the trademark has been registered for, is it  state registered trademark or federal trademark filed with the US Patent and Trademark Office (and the list goes on).

Following is helpful video on differences between trademark, patents, and copyright, domain names and business names
https://youtu.be/4cIBcl7dD4w

For further reading the following page on USPTO.gov offers very useful information
https://www.uspto.gov/trademarks-getting-started/trademark-basics

.

Comment: But it is a spelling mistake. The names are different. Can I not report the map listing as copyright and ask for it to be removed on that basis. On mobile search, the map listings take up the first screen view and it does not show SERPs until further in the fold. 100% it affects brand visibility and customers.

Comment: Have eta on my initial answer, is easier to expand on there rather than via commenting